# Updating View Content via Ajax

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

Im trying to update a view content but Im stuck at the part when I have to reload the data, I´ve achieved to get the data again to the view via en Action that returns a Json, but I do not know how to refresh the content using that data.

This is the ajax call:

```
window.setInterval(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: "/Home/ModelsUpdate",

                dataType: "json",
                cache: false,
                error: (error) => {
                    console.log(JSON.stringify(error));
                },

                    success: function (result) {
                        console.log(result);


//THIS IS WHERE I NEED TO USE THE DATA AND RELOAD THE VIEW CONTENT

                    }

                });
            },
            15000);
```

And the HTML is a foreach like this:

```
<table>
    <div class="row">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {           
                <div class="card hoverable">

                    <div class="progress" style="background: white" value="0" data-acr="@item.Acronym"></div>                       
                            <div class="row">
                               <h7>@item.Name</h7>                           
                            </div>  
                    </div>        
        } 
   </div>
</table>
```

I need to update this foreach every 15 seconds with the Ajax.

Is that posible?

Comment: i think you need to use an MVC Update Panel in order to refresh the table the way you want to. The problem is that the HTML that you posted isnt what is ACTUALLY on the page. You've got Razor code in there and that is run on the server side. If you view page source you will see that the actual html in the browser contains all the generated divs and what not. You wont see @foreach()

Comment: @victor So the answer is to use a partial view? Like...getting all that html content in a partial view and calling it from the ajax? If it is like that please let me know how to call it from the ajax. Thanks!

Comment: I cant write up the whole answer for you. Id suggest you do some reading up on ajax and how to use it and also the differences between server side and client side code.